# match.call for function with order matched too

Tags: r

I have an R function that accepts both named arguments and others through `...`. For example:

```
f <- function(a, b, ...) {

  mc <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)[-1])

  ### Lots of procesing on mc

  return(mc)

}
```

So a user might input the call `f(a = 3, c = 3, b = 3)`, which returns this list:

```
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 3
```

However, the order of the output does not match the order of the function input arguments. It's clear *why* that is so, since `...` is at the end of the function arguments. But I'm wondering if there is a way to retain the original ordering, even if both named and `...` arguments are used. So the output list would look like:

```
$a
[1] 3

$c
[1] 3

$b
[1] 3
```

In my research, there is nothing in `call`, `match.call`, or `formals` that allows me to look up the specific input ordering of the call in this case. Any ideas? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sys.call()` instead.

```
f <- function(a, b, ...) {
  mc <- as.list(sys.call()[-1])
  return(mc)

}

f(a = 3, c = 3, b = 3)

# $a
# [1] 3
# 
# $c
# [1] 3
# 
# $b
# [1] 3
```